# Why is this modelstate not valid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

So I am working on a .NET Core application and stumbled upon this. My modelstate is not valid and it gives no errors or whatsoever.

My normal model class:

```
    public class MoederbladABNA
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Naam_betaler_of_Begunstigde { get; set; }

        public string IBAN_Rekeningnummer { get; set; }

        public string BIC_Code_Bank { get; set; }

        public string Valuta_Soort { get; set; }

        public string Bedrag { get; set; }

        public string Adres_Begunstigde { get; set; }

        public string Woonplaats_Betaler_of_Begunstigde { get; set; }

        public string Land_code { get; set; }

        public string Transactiekosten { get; set; }

        public string Betalingskenmerk { get; set; }

        public string Omschrijving { get; set; }

        public string Machtigingskenmerk { get; set; }

        public string Datum_van_machtiging { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Incassodatum { get; set; }

        public bool Gemuteerd { get; set; }

        public Reden MutatieReden { get; set; }

        public bool FirstIncasso { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Reden
    {
        [Display(Name = "Niet van toepassing")] NietVanToepassing = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Administratieve reden")] AdministratieveReden = 2,
        [Display(Name = "Niet akkoord klant")] NietAkkoordKlant = 3,
        [Display(Name = "Incasso blokkade")] IncassoBlokkade = 4,
    }
```

My viewmodel class which the create action uses:

```
    public class MoederbladViewModels
    {
        public class AddMoederbladViewModels
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            [DisplayName("Naam betaler of begunstigde")]
            public string Naam_betaler_of_Begunstigde { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            [DisplayName("IBAN (Rekeningnummer)")]
            public string IBAN_Rekeningnummer { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            [DisplayName("BIC Code")]
            public string BIC_Code_Bank { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            [DisplayName("Valuta")]
            public string Valuta_Soort { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            [DisplayName("Bedrag")]
            [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{1,2}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Dat is geen geldig bedrag.")]
            public string Bedrag { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            [DisplayName("Adres begunstigde")]
            public string Adres_Begunstigde { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            [DisplayName("Woonplaats betaler/begunstigde")]
            public string Woonplaats_Betaler_of_Begunstigde { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            [DisplayName("Landcode")]
            public string Land_code { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            [DisplayName("Transactiekosten")]
            public string Transactiekosten { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            [DisplayName("Betalingskenmerk")]
            public string Betalingskenmerk { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            [DisplayName("Omschrijving")]
            public string Omschrijving { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            [DisplayName("Machtigingskenmerk")]
            public string Machtigingskenmerk { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("Datum van machtiging")]
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            public string Datum_van_machtiging { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
            public string Incassodatum { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            [Display(Name = "Mutatie")]
            public bool Gemuteerd { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Reden voor mutatie")]
            public Reden MutatieReden { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Het veld '{0}' is verplicht")]
            [Display(Name = "First incasso")]
            public bool FirstIncasso { get; set; }
        }

        public enum Reden
        {
            [Display(Name = "Niet van toepassing")] NietVanToepassing = 1,
            [Display(Name = "Administratieve reden")] AdministratieveReden = 2,
            [Display(Name = "Niet akkoord klant")] NietAkkoordKlant = 3,
            [Display(Name = "Incasso blokkade")] IncassoBlokkade = 4,
        }
    }
```

My view:

```
@model bespaartoppers.ViewModels.MoederbladViewModels.AddMoederbladViewModels
@addTagHelper *, InvariantDecimalTagHelper
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Nieuwe aanmaken</h2>

<h4>Moederblad ABNA</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Naam_betaler_of_Begunstigde" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Naam_betaler_of_Begunstigde" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Naam_betaler_of_Begunstigde" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="IBAN_Rekeningnummer" class="control-label"></label>
                <input data-rule-bankaccountNL="true" asp-for="IBAN_Rekeningnummer" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="IBAN_Rekeningnummer" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BIC_Code_Bank" class="control-label"></label>
                <input data-rule-bic="true" asp-for="BIC_Code_Bank" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BIC_Code_Bank" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Valuta_Soort" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Valuta_Soort" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Bedrag" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Bedrag" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Bedrag" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Adres_Begunstigde" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Adres_Begunstigde" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Adres_Begunstigde" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Woonplaats_Betaler_of_Begunstigde" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Woonplaats_Betaler_of_Begunstigde" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Woonplaats_Betaler_of_Begunstigde" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Land_code" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Land_code" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Transactiekosten" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Transactiekosten" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Betalingskenmerk" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Betalingskenmerk" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Betalingskenmerk" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Omschrijving" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Omschrijving" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Omschrijving" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Machtigingskenmerk" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Machtigingskenmerk" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Machtigingskenmerk" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Datum_van_machtiging" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Datum_van_machtiging" class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/JJJJ"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Datum_van_machtiging" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Incassodatum (optioneel)</label>
                <textarea asp-for="Incassodatum" placeholder="DD/MM/JJJJ" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Incassodatum" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Gemuteerd" class="control-label"></label>
                <div id="mutatie" class="checkbox">
                    <input asp-for="Gemuteerd" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Gemuteerd" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="mutatiereden" class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MutatieReden" class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="dropdown" style="color:black!important">
                    <select asp-for="MutatieReden" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Reden>()">
                        <option selected="selected" value="">---Selecteer---</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstIncasso" class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(item => item.FirstIncasso)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Aanmaken" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Terug naar de lijst</a>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#mutatiereden').hide();
    $('#mutatie').change(function () {
        $('#mutatiereden').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

The controller code:

```
       // POST: Moederblads/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Naam_betaler_of_Begunstigde,IBAN_Rekeningnummer,Land_code,BIC_Code_Bank,Bedrag,Adres_Begunstigde,Woonplaats_Betaler_of_Begunstigde,Betalingskenmerk,Transactiekosten,Valuta_Soort,Omschrijving,Machtigingskenmerk,Datum_van_machtiging,Incassodatum,Gemuteerd,MutatieReden,FirstIncasso")]AddMoederbladViewModels addMoederbladViewModels)
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var moederblad = new MoederbladABNA()
                {
                    Naam_betaler_of_Begunstigde = addMoederbladViewModels.Naam_betaler_of_Begunstigde,
                    IBAN_Rekeningnummer = addMoederbladViewModels.IBAN_Rekeningnummer,
                    Land_code = addMoederbladViewModels.Land_code,
                    BIC_Code_Bank = addMoederbladViewModels.BIC_Code_Bank,
                    Bedrag = addMoederbladViewModels.Bedrag,
                    Adres_Begunstigde = addMoederbladViewModels.Adres_Begunstigde,
                    Woonplaats_Betaler_of_Begunstigde = addMoederbladViewModels.Woonplaats_Betaler_of_Begunstigde,
                    Betalingskenmerk = addMoederbladViewModels.Betalingskenmerk,
                    Transactiekosten = addMoederbladViewModels.Transactiekosten,
                    Valuta_Soort = addMoederbladViewModels.Valuta_Soort,
                    Omschrijving = addMoederbladViewModels.Omschrijving,
                    Machtigingskenmerk = addMoederbladViewModels.Machtigingskenmerk,
                    Datum_van_machtiging = addMoederbladViewModels.Datum_van_machtiging,
                    Incassodatum = addMoederbladViewModels.Incassodatum,
                    Gemuteerd = addMoederbladViewModels.Gemuteerd,
                    FirstIncasso = addMoederbladViewModels.FirstIncasso
                };

                _context.Add(moederblad);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(addMoederbladViewModels);
        }
```

So when debugging and hovering over this line:
var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

It shows 0 errors, I compared all the properties from the viewmodel class and the normal class, checked all the bind values in the controller, only thing I could think of is the Id being 0 in that context, but it is auto increment so that should not give a issue.

Comment: When debugging: Are you entering the _if (ModelState.IsValid)_ following part?

Comment: Yes I do @schlonzo

Comment: Then I guess it's the datacontext complaining that your model's state is not valid. Are you using _EntityFramework_ with code first?

Comment: Yes code first. @schlonzo

Comment: OK, hmmmmm, you are saying there is no error happening. How do you know there is an error?

Comment: Because the modelstate is not valid.

Comment: What's invalid in your ModelState? Try to be more specific if you can. The Id property being 0 wouldn't rise any errors because it doesn't have any annotations like Required annotation), and 0 is a valid integer. Which property is null?

Comment: Hmm, found it. It is the enum property which is 0, but it is not required so how can this give an error? It says value "" is invalid. @spartanroger

Comment: Interesting. I believe that because it ain't a null value, it should be one of your enumeration possible values (1,2,3,4). I think "NietVanToepassing" should also work. In JSON, null or no existing at all is basically the same, but you can save some bits if you remove null values from your JSON. ;)

Comment: Thanks! @spartanroger